# Questions including tags in their titles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, title

Everyday I come across many questions that has their "tag" included in the title. For example:

- How to detect numbers in String in Java?
- What's  the fastest way of reading a file in C?
- Python: How to combine two lists together?
- How to time travel in Java?

I edit every question like that and remove the "tag" from the title (in rare cases it cannot be removed as it's part of the question and including it is fine).

I thought it might be helpful and useful if a warning popup appears when the poster enters "in {language}" or "{language} -" in the title when the language is tagged.

Comment: Related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92763/dissuade-askers-from-putting-tags-in-question-titles

Comment: @CoolGuy exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I still think that it'll help the community to have such a popup.

Comment: I'd argue "in {language}" is an example of it being part of the question and thus there is no need to remove it. (You *can* remove it, but doing so is a waste of your time.)

Comment: I guess for some of the more generic question titles it will be (or become) necessary. For example the system doesn't allow identical question titles and *How to combine to lists together?* will have a totally different answer in C# to Python, but we can't rely on just the tags to disambiguate them because of the identical title limitation.

Comment: 9 out of 10 questions that start with a tag also include a *Hi*, unformatted codeblocks and a *Thanks in advantage*. They are thankful edit targets.

Comment: Last time I checked this, I counted 62% of questions having one of their tags in the title.  A feature request that's going to prevent 2/3rds of the questions getting posted on the first attempt strikes me as a non-starter.  It would be nice if SE would just use [status-denied] and get it over with, not much point in bringing this up repeatedly.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not saying it should be prevented, but maybe posters can be at least notified.

Comment: Alas, this question title includes [meta-tag:tags] and [meta-tag:title]. One should endeavor to try to figure out how to remove those tags from this title. I'm glad you didn't include that tag [meta-tag:questions], or there would be even more difficulty trying to word the title.

Comment: @MichaelT Sometimes you cannot ask without including the tag in the title. I wouldn't remove "How to connect Java to MySQL database"..

Comment: @BoltClock Does "in {platform}" have the same consideration as "in {language}"?

Comment: @nhgrif: Sure, why not?

Comment: Could you then, provide your rewordings of the tagless versions of the titles you have in the bulleted list? I don't see how "How to connect Java to MySQL database" is that different from your examples of "How to detect numbers in String in Java?" or "How to time travel in Java?".

Comment: @MichaelT Because you cannot ask "How to connect to MySQL database", it'll be very vague, you cannot tell what poster really wants to connect. But asking "How to detect numbers in String", when Java is tagged, must be referring finding numbers in String using Java..

Comment: @MichaelT Regarding "How to time travel in Java", I would close if as "too broad" :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun "How do you connect to a MySQL database" is just as good (or poor) of a title as "How to detect numbers in a String".

Comment: @MichaelT In your opinion. But my opinion is different; If I see "How do you connect to a MySQL database" when Java is tagged, I might understand (only from title) that OP wants to connect to MySQL from Java code, but not necessarily. But if they ask "How to find numbers... in Java", I'm sure what they mean.

Comment: @MichaelT Anyway, this argument will never end. I got your point and I can understand you, I just have a different opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Help Center page on tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) includes this:

> ### Should I use tags in titles?
>
> You should not force a tag into your title. Because the tags appear
>   below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with
>   the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be
>   able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.
>
> ...
>
> The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are
>   organic to the conversational tone of the title.

A few formats are supplied - a simple rule of thumb is that if you can remove the *"tag"* without needing to rearrange the grammar around it, do so.

Comment: "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title." At that point, I wouldn't consider them "tags" so much as "keywords". You often need keywords in order to write a clear and concise title. Removing keywords from a title effectively makes it *worse*.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like a non issue... the language has a lot to do with the problems and solutions. If you start to get language agnostic, you start to have questions that would be considered more appropriate for Programmers.SE.

We already have a way to filter based on tags.

I really don't see any problem with the titles nor what would be improved by your suggested fix. "Hey, you mention Java in your title, and you also used [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)... good job on matching them up."