# Discussion: Block question creation when the title contains the tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As demonstrated by my regrettably bad question title...

How hard would it really be to prevent someone from creating a new question where the title contains one of the tags they are also using? Aren't we all tired of seeing questions that start like "C#: " or "ASP .NET MVC - " by now?

Has this been tried or at least discussed before?

Comment: Where would you stop though? If you implemented that rule they would just switched to adding it at the end. And it is allowed to have the name of a technology in the title as long as it occurs as natural language

Comment: This has been discussed many times, unfortunately I can't seem to find one. I believe the consensus is generally that there are common uses of many tag names that are completely valid, so blocking that wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf _they would just switched to adding it at the end_ this is easily solved by regular expressions.

Comment: @TinyGiant Like  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290007/questions-including-tags-in-their-titles?rq=1

Comment: @Yuck How would you think that would solve it?  How can you write a regular expression that would check if something is Natural Language or not?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Of course, why didnt I think to search _that_. What a useful title.

Comment: Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles  where they removed bracketed tags from titles

Answer (score 10):

While we don't want people to stick tags in their question titles just to put them there, we don't want to penalize someone for asking a question where the tag appears *naturally*. Consider this title:

> [GCC and Clang disagree about C++17 constexpr lambda captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386415/gcc-and-clang-disagree-about-c17-constexpr-lambda-captures)

It would be extremely awkward to ask this question without mentioning the tags GCC, Clang, and C++17 in the title. Though admittedly, this particular question neglects to use either of the compiler tags, but it would have been entirely reasonable to do so.

Take the tags in the title away, and what are you left with? "Some compilers I can't mention disagree about a feature from a language version I can't say?" That's a lot less descriptive of a title.