# Do tags help in Google searches?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

I was tagging a Bash [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50259869/6862601) with generic tags like `string` and `replace` and saw a couple of members expressing their doubt about the usefulness of such tags in the context.

My guess is that tags do help in Google searches.  Am I right?

Comment: They do, indirectly, the primary tag of the question is prefixed to the question title.  Something SO had to do to battle the vampire sites who figured out this SEO trick first.  And the reason for much strife between questioners and editors, the latter trying to enforce that the question title should not contain the tag name.  They lost.  So your edit is quite unlikely to be helpful, it will prefix the google hit with "string" instead of "bash".

Comment: I don't think anybody could be an expert in "string" or "replace". The tags smell kinda meta-ish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The tag that is displayed first in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220932/323179) has an impact on Google searches:

> According to Moz's testing and experience, keywords closer to the beginning of your title tag may have more impact on search rankings. In addition, user experience research shows that people may scan as few as the first two words of a headline.
>   <sub>[Title Tag | Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)</sub>

Whether this is helpful or not depends on the question and what tag is chosen. [Shog recommends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163409/323179) "to avoid having extremely common tags that are more or less meaningless", which often applies to generic tags.

Making the title itself really good is probably more important for SEO.

Comment: I have been actively removing superfluous tags in the question title. I have edited questions such as "Swift - How do I create a URLSession?" to just "How do I create a URLSession?" with the assumption that tags do not belong in the question. Is this a bad thing to be doing?

Comment: @picciano I think that's a good edit. If "Swift" is in the title, then the next most popular tag that's not in the title will be added too (it might end up looking like "ios - Swift - How do I create a URLSession?"). If "Swift" is not in the title and it is the most popular tag, then it will be added (and the title will be "swift - How do I create a URLSession?").

Comment: @picciano yes, it's actually good. Titles are supposed to read like titles, the tags would then be added automagically by the system.

Comment: @picciano It is perfectly acceptable to include a tag in the title in way such that the title reads organically. In the Help Center, see [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and well as [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290011/1497596) and [Boltclock's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290007/questions-including-tags-in-their-titles/290011#comment175745_290011). Improving your example title: "Create a URLSession with Swift?" Note that "How do I" is considered noise and it should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I have only been removing tags from titles where they do not read organically and I will continue doing so based on this feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no.  Google is going to be using the actual text of the question when indexing the page.  If you have a question about replacing strings, those words should no doubt be in the page somewhere.

The biggest value in tagging is allowing SO users to find questions that they're interested in interacting with by following tags for those topics, and ignoring tags for topics that they aren't interested in.  The real notable impact tags have on searches is that the most popular tag in the question is added to the question's title, if it wasn't already there (browser title, not title as in the header on the page), and the page's title tends to be weighted much more heavily in web searches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @codeforester Google is very secretive about their SEO calculations.  They most certainly don't document the specifics of how it works.  You can find lots of people's guesses and theories about how it works by searching Google though.

Comment: Since the tags are part of the page content, it "might" help somewhat.

Comment: @picciano As I said in the answer, if the question is actually about those things, presumably those words are already showing up in the page's content elsewhere, in which case the tags aren't adding anything.  If they aren't, then the real fix is to edit the question or post an answer to actually include the terms that the question is asking about.